# Vertical align list bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to make many lists, and my lists have various sizes. 
I'd like to force them to be sticked under the previous line's list, like "Chapitre 7" on the picture, without care of the size. Does somebody know how to do it ? `vertical-align` doesn'works...

My code :

    `<div class="row">
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul>
</div>`

And the `<ul>` are having various sizes

[image: My Site]

EDIT : 
Solved with a `<div class="clearfix"><\div>` every three blocs !

Comment: Hi, you need to post some code that replicates the issue so that we have a [mcve] we can work with and solve for you.

Comment: Just did it, sorry !

Comment: Use a [responsive reset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) (AKA clearfix) every 3 `col-*` http://www.codeply.com/go/G4JG4GUSbY

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want your list to just be displayed one UNDER the other? (and not side by side?)

If so, try adding a `<br>` at the end of each `<ul>`
This forces the next element to be in a new line (under the previous one)

I.e-

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul><br>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul><br>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul><br>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul><br>
    <ul class="col-md-4"></ul><br>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the big vertical emptiness between two columns